# How to fill Empoyer information for freelancer US Visa

Tags: greencard

I work remotely as a freelancer (mostly on **Upwork.com**). I recently have won the **US Diversity Visa Lottery** and now I am filling in the **DS-260 form**. In order to provide current occupation information, I have to give the name and address of my current employer. There is no option to mark those fields as 'Does not Apply' there. So how should I fill in the Employer information?

Comment: @scaaahu - my interpretation is that the OP is currently living & working outside the US, and therefore does not currently have any US income or tax returns.

Comment: Isn’t there an option such as ‘self-employed’ or ‘freelance’?

Comment: @Traveller,  no, there isn't. 'Other' only. If I select 'other', system asks me to fill Name, Address etc of an Employer.

Comment: i'm selectee of the current fiscal year & have the same question, for i'm a freelancer and don't know if i should name it as primary occupation and put my personal address, as i'm working from home. Or i should leave it 'unemployed'. As you've posted this 3 years ago i assume you've already passed the interview and are in the USA. So, what is your experience with this situation and your advice to me? Thanks.

Comment: I might be in the same situation, so can you tell me what you did with your ds-260?